# Image alpha composite with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I want to implement these steps:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
from skimage.io import *
import numpy as np

imA = cv2.imread('C.jpg')
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
imA = cv2.cvtColor(imA, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(imA, 5, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
imshow(opening)
show()
imF = cv2.imread('157969651.jpg')
imF = cv2.cvtColor(imF, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)

imB = cv2.imread('images.jpg')
imB = cv2.cvtColor(imB, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)

imF[:, :, 0] *= opening
imF[:, :, 1] *= opening
imF[:, :, 2] *= opening
imF[:, :, 3] *= opening

imB[:, :, 0] *= (1 - opening)
imB[:, :, 1] *= (1 - opening)
imB[:, :, 2] *= (1 - opening)
imB[:, :, 3] *= (1 - opening)

res = imF + imB

imshow(res)
show()
```

Result:

[image]

I don't know what's wrong in this code. Anyone can see what wrong in my steps?

Comment: `imB[:,:,0]*=(255-opening)`. The same for the others

Comment: Not working give me white sceen

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70578600/how-to-merge-one-rgba-and-one-rgb-images-in-opencv (add a transparent PNG over JPG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alpha not is a channel, is a mask.

My Solution:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

foreground = cv2.imread('foreground.jpg')
background = cv2.imread('background.jpg')
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)

foreground_gray = cv2.cvtColor(foreground, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, mask = cv2.threshold(foreground_gray, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

opening = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

output = np.zeros(foreground.shape, dtype=foreground.dtype)

for i in range(3):
    output[:, :, i] = background[:, :, i] *(opening/255) + foreground[:, :, i] *(1-opening/255)

cv2.imshow("img", output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**foreground.jpg**

[image]

**background.jpg**

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much you divide the result by 255 to save range right ?!

Answer (score 0):

Check your mask are in 0-1 range, not in 0-255.

Comment: result the same

Comment: And use RGB or BGR, no alpha channel please. Or just not apply blending to alpha. You alpha is your mask here. And ensure your images in float or double format too.

Comment: Thanks For help your answer help me

Comment: @AndreySmorodov why do you suggest the images to be of float or double format?

Comment: Just because mixing must have values in range [0-1] and resulting value is res=m*A+(1-m)*B. If you will multiply it in integer format, you will get wrong result. If m=1 we have pure A as result, if m=0 we will have pure B. And if m is 0.4 for instance, we will have res=0.4*A+0.6*B. If both A and B are in correct range, the result will be in correct range to.

Comment: @AndreySmorodov +1